# Cannot ping/reach netcomm nf4v router from another subnet

Tags: networking, router

My network topology:

```
                            mac
                        192.168.1.4
                             |
internet - netcom 192.168.1.1-192.168.1.253 linux 192.168.2.1-192.168.2.2 windows
```

- netcom is NAT gateway to internet
- netcom has a static route to
  192.168.2.0/24 via 192.168.1.253
- mac has a static route to 192.168.2.0/24 via 192.168.1.253
- mac has a default gw of 192.168.1.1
- linux has default gw of 192.168.1.1
- linux has port forwarding and disabled firewall
- windows has a default gw of 192.168.2.1
- mac can ping windows, linux, and netcom
- linux can ping windows, mac, and netcom
- **windows can ping mac and linux BUT NOT netcom**
- **netcom can ping mac and linux BUT NOT windows**

lastly, i ran tcpdump while trying to ping netcom from windows (and vice versa) and it shows packets are going through the correct interfaces, any idea what could be wrong?

ping from netcom to windows shows the following logs:

ping in netcom:

```
 > ping 192.168.2.2
app: echo 1 > /var/ping_dns_status
PING 192.168.2.2 (192.168.2.2): 56 data bytes

--- 192.168.2.2 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

tcpdump in linux:

```
00:03:12.441283  In 18:f1:45:75:2c:24 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.2.2: ICMP echo request, id 5784, seq 0, length 64
00:03:12.441341 Out 00:0c:29:0b:03:c3 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.2.2: ICMP echo request, id 5784, seq 0, length 64
00:03:12.441829  In 00:0c:29:e9:17:84 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 192.168.2.2 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo reply, id 5784, seq 0, length 64
00:03:12.441850 Out 00:0c:29:0b:03:b9 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 192.168.2.2 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo reply, id 5784, seq 0, length 64
```

wireshark on windows:

```
192.168.1.1     192.168.2.2     ICMP    98      Echo (ping) request  id=0x1698, seq=0/0, ttl=63 (reply in 2548)
192.168.2.2     192.168.1.1     ICMP    98      Echo (ping) reply    id=0x1698, seq=0/0, ttl=128 (request in 2547)
```

Comment: Does tcpdump _on Windows_ (or Wireshark) show that it is receiving the ping packets from netcom? (And is it trying to reply?)

Comment: @grawity i've added the logs in netcom (ping) linux (tcpdump) and windows (wireshark)

Comment: Does the netcomm has firewall enabled?

Comment: @ChanTzish, don't know how to check that, the netcomm has a very minimal (probably linux) os, and not even sure if it has firewall commands built in

Comment: @ChanTzish ok, i tried iptables -L and it shows a lot of rules, not sure which one in particular could be dropping my packets

Comment: I fount this manual https://support.netcommwireless.com/sites/default/files/NF4V-User-Guide.pdf please chek under "Access Control -- Services" section maybe you have to change the icmp settings? also check the "security" under "advanced setup" section

Comment: I would also suggest to ping from the netcomm to 192.168.2.1

Comment: icmp settings cannot be unset/unchecked in "Access Control - Services" and ping 192.168.2.1 from netcomm is also not getting replies

Answer (score 0):

on linux machine packet forwarding is disabled by default. Try to run commands:

**iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT**

**iptables -A FORWARD -o eth1 -j ACCEPT**

(and same two commands on another network interfaces instead of eth1)

**sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1**

and add to /etc/sysctl.conf

**net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0**

Comment: firewall is disabled in linux and forwarding is enabled that's why mac can ping windows